# How to do oauth for Excel add-in?

Tags: google-oauth

I want to do oauth inside an Excel add-in. I have an embedded browser where I can open the oauth url. Which oauth options I should go for ?

1. manual copy/paste
2. programmatic extraction

(https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp)

As all apps will be manually verified by Google, so I am asking before developing the solution. I want something which will be approved by Google.